# Как перебрать значения ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

Есть 
    int num;
    ArrayList l_int;
    Map map = new HashMap();

Когда перебираю значения пишу так:

```
for (int i=0; i < l_int.size(); i++){
    num = l_int.get(i);
    xxxx = map.get(num)
}
```

Как перебрать значения не прибегая к промежуточному присваиванию num, а сразу брать значения из списка l_int?

Comment: цикл for each пробовал использовать? информация о нем https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/cikl-for-each/

Comment: Да, спасибо, все оказалось просто.